# excel download with Flask-RestPlus?

Tags: python, download, flask-restplus

How to implement an API endpoint to download excel file using Flask-RestPlus?

Previously I had implemented similar function using Pyramid. However that method didn't work here.
Here is the old code snippet:

```
workBook = openpyxl.Workbook()
fileName = 'Report.xls'
response = Response(content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel',
                            content_disposition='attachment; filename=%s' % fileName)
workBook.save(response)
return response
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

**send_from_directory** provides a secure way to quickly expose static files from an upload folder or something similar when using Flask-RestPlus

```
from flask import send_from_directory
import os

@api.route('/download')
class Download(Resource):
    def get(self):
        fileName = 'Report.xls'
        return send_from_directory(os.getcwd(), fileName, as_attachment=True)
```

*I have assumed file is in current working directory. The path to download file can be adjusted accordingly.*